# Go to next position in html page when clicking a button - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my application I am using Jquery / Javascript I want to implement one functionality.

I have few divs like this,

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="div5"></div>
<div id="div6"></div>
```

I know that to go to specific position on that page, I can use,

`<a href="#Div4">go to div 4</a>`

Now, I have two buttons already that are going to the previous div & going to next div.

I.e.,

- Previous Button -> clicking that it will go to previous div
- Next Button -> clicking that will go to next div

How can I do this using this two buttons?

Also, I only want to show the div where the button points. I.e., if clicking next button points to Div3 then only Div3 should be shown & other divs should be hidden.

One way of doing this previous & next functionality is that when I introduce one variable which will be incremented or decremented when next or previous button clicked & depending on count of that variable I will decide which Div to point. I.e., if variable value is 5 then I will point to Div5.

Any other way any one know to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post your JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the location.hash property and navigate around that using cached numbers, so assuming you have two buttons: "next" and "prev":

```
var marker = 0;

$('#next').click(function(){
  marker++;

  location.hash = "div" + marker;
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
  marker--;
  location.hash = "div" + marker;
});
```

Obviously this needs expanded on, but you have the basic premise.

Comment: This is what I was thinking to do, but problem is that I just want to show active div & not other divs

Comment: So what I'm understanding is, you would like to only show one div at a time? If that is the case then in the click you should add a class called active on the div you want to show (the next div) and then remove the class from all others.

Comment: Do you think that it will be use full when I have 200 Divs ?

Comment: @vaibhavshah, yes that solution should work no matter how many div's you have.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery has next and prev selector to do this

```
    var currentDiv=$("#div1");

    $("#btnNext").click(function()
    {currentDiv=$(currentDiv);$(currentDiv).next().show();});

    $("#btnPrev").click(function()currentDiv=$(currentDiv);   
    {$(currentDiv).prev().show();});
```

Note currentDiv should be a global variable.